# C program compiled in cygwin with make: "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to run a code by someone which can be perfectly "make"ed in linux and it works fine. 
When I "make" in cygwin and run it I get the "cannot execute binary file" error. 
When I "file" the executable it says:

```
$ file kmeans
kmeans: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Does "for GNU/Linux 2.6.9" I can't run it inside the Windows? Or what do you think the problem it?

Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

[Here are my files,](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~khashab2/files/2015_constrained_clustering/kmeans_code.zip) in case you want to take a look.

Update: my gcc version: gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)

Comment: What's the value tor `Target` when you run `gcc -v`?

Comment: gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)

Comment: Every time you post a screenshot of a console, Buddha kills a kitten.

Comment: @Daniel I asked for the Target, not the compiler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a `kmeans` (linux binary)  and `kmeans.exe` Windows/cygwin version of your programm.
When you call `./kmeans` you try to execute the Linux version in Windows.

Try to run `kmeans.exe`.